# C++ How to use string::functions on smartpointer<string>

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, string-function

In order to avoid unnecessary variables, is there a way to make

`int var = sharedPtrStringVar.length();`

and other funtions of String work with smart pointers?

Until now I`ve been copying the string from the pointer into a temp var but isn't there a better way (without using vectors)?

thnak you Yksisarvinen that was exaclty what i wanted to kinow

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get

Comment: just wondering: how do you copy the string from the smartpointer if you dont know how to access it?

Comment: Instead of editing the question with a thank you, you can just accept the answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similarly to raw pointer, you use `->` operator to access object members, so your code would be

```
int var = sharedPtrStringVar->length();
```

Same applies to dereference operator `*`:

```
int var = (*sharedPtrStringVar).length();
std::cout << *sharedPtrStringVar; //print the content
```